# beautifulsoup webscraper problem: can't find tables on webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

I want to get tables from [this](https://www.flashscore.pl/pilka-nozna/) website with this code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.flashscore.pl/pilka-nozna/'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'soccer'})

print(len(containers))
```

But when I try to check how much tables I get by `print(len(containers))`, I get 0.
Any solutions?

edit:
[image: image of contained tables]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's possible the page is dynamic. you can use [requests-html](https://html.python-requests.org/) which allows you to let the page render before pulling the html, or you can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/), as I did here.

This resulted in 42 elements of table class="soccer"

```
import bs4 
from selenium import webdriver 

url = 'https://www.flashscore.pl/pilka-nozna/'

browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)

html = browser.page_source
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')  

containers = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'soccer'})

browser.close()
```

```
In  [11]: print(len(containers))
42
```